# Python to read stdin from other source continously

Tags: python, bash, stdin, watch

Is it possible to allow Python to read from stdin from another source such as a file continually? Basically I'm trying to allow my script to use stdin to echo input and I'd like to use a file or external source to interact with it (while remaining open).

An example might be (input.py):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

line = sys.stdin.readline()

while line:
    print line,
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Executing this directly I can continuously enter text and it echos back while the script remains alive. If you want to use an external source though such as a file or input from bash then the script exits immediately after receiving input:

```
$ echo "hello" | python input.py
hello
$
```

Ultimately what I'd like to do is:

```
$ tail -f file | python input.py
```

Then if the file updates have input.py echo back anything that is added to file while remaining open. Maybe I'm approaching this the wrong way or I'm simply clueless, but is there a way to do it?

Comment: So did you try this? If it doesn't work, you probably hit problem with buffering - [have a look](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)

Comment: It reads the file, but if I update the file the changes are not reflected in the pythons stdin/stdout.

Comment: `tail -f file` will keep emitting data appended to the file. Updates appended to the file work... are you doing it some other way?

Comment: @RoryZipher Tail will only follow if file is **appended** to, not changed. So not what would you do with say, vim. Try `echo "stuff" >> file` to test it.

Comment: Yes, I'm appending the file. for example if the file contained "hello", then i run the command, append the file on the next line with "world" and save it it's not shown in the stdin/stdout of the currently executing process.

Comment: So probably the buffering issue, cause it's working perfectly for me just as you provide it. Mind that by appending I mean that file has to be opened with `O_APPEND` in `open` params.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Doing `echo "something else" >> file` works fine, but if I use an external editor and save it then it seems to ignore it.

Comment: The editor might be creating a new file instead of overwriting the original file. Try using `tail -F -f file`. This will reopen the file if it gets renamed.

Comment: @Barmar is right, editors tend to write to a temporary file then overwrite the existing file on save.

Comment: @tdelaney That wouldn't cause this problem. I'm suggesting they write to a temporary file and rename it to the original filename. This is how Emacs works by default, although it has customization variables that change it.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes that works, but with one caveat... I need to insert a line break for it to read the appended text, otherwise it won't update. Not a big deal, as I could include a line break. If you want to put your comment as an answer I'll gladly accept it - thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-F` option to `tail` to make it reopen the file if it gets renamed or deleted and a new file is created with the original name. Some editors write the file this way, and logfile rotation scripts also usually work this way (they rename the original file to `filename.1`, and create a new log file).

```
$ tail -F file | python input.py
```

Comment: This didn't work on my linux mint and I'm a bit surprised that `tail` even accepted both `-F` and `-f`, which tells it to follow by name and file descriptor. But `tail -f F file | python input.py` "worked" - Did you mean just `tail -F file | python input.py`?

Comment: I misread the documentation, I thought `-F` modified the behavior of `-f`, rather than being an alternative.